# Деньги, монеты, мелочь, - нужен ещё один синоним!

Tags: синонимы

> Так что теперь фонтан приходится периодически отключать. Это довольно
>   занятное зрелище, когда воду спускают и собирают туристские
>   «пожертвования». Деньги сгребают специальными лопатками и раскладывают
>   по пластиковым вёдрам, чтобы потом начать чистить раствором дно,
>   которое в туристический сезон просто не разглядеть под слоем мелочи.
>   Коммунальные службы сначала негодовали, а теперь каждый год хвастают в
>   газетах своим умопомрачительным уловом, уточняя, что все эти деньги
>   уходят на благотворительность.

Как Вы смотрите на:

*...что весь этот «улов» уходит на благотворительность.* Ой, улов же буквально только что был/есть... Тогда нужен синоним к улову... Доход? Но рядом "уходят", обратно ж однокоренное...

Где править?

А то я уже изварьировалась с кидать-бросать-опускать-погружать...

Comment: ... внушительным доходом, уточняя, что все деньги идут...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А если так:  "...уточняя, что все эти **средства** уходят на благотворительность".

Answer (score 1):

Много лет назад, когда мы были в *Ласточкином гнезде*, мой одноклассник сказал об этом обычае: **"возвратные побросашки"** ( надо же, вспомнила ).
Возможно, подойдет - как "изварьированность"?

**Дополнение**
Если денежки в фонтан *набросаны*, тогда такой вариант: *памятные наброски* или *наброски на память*. Или, собственно, - **денежки, денЮжки.**

Comment: Спасибо, Римма! Тут я  "со своими" беседую, а то - чужая речь, с ею надо аккуратненько... А в своей бы - запросто! Хотя "побросашка" очень далеко от моей лексики.

Comment: Одноклассник сейчас репортером в газете работает. У него удивительно подходящая фамилия -  для нашего сайта - ШКОЛА